# Do I need to add tile images to my Windows Phone 7.1 in order to target Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I have a Windows Phone app that targets OS 7.1 and I wish to be available for Windows Phone 8 devices as well. As I understand it I needn't do anything code-wise to make this possible. However, must I add new tile images to get it certified? According to [App submission requirements for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184844%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) the XAP must include more images for Windows Phone 8 than for Windows Phone 7 (see Default Tile images under section 4.7.2), is this the case here or does it only apply to Windows Phone apps targeting OS 8.0 and higher?

Comment: What do you mean by app images? Screenshots for Windows Phone Store? or images (icons and so on) inside the app?

Comment: Sorry, meant Default Tile images under section 4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is already available as is for WP8 devices.

That's not clear what do you mean by images.

**If you are talking about screenshots for Marketplace:**

If you have a separate XAP you'll have to add screenshots to it.

Nowadays it's enough to add a set of screenshots in  WXGA (1280 x 768) resolution.

**If you are talking about icons and other images you use inside the app:**

- you should add images in  WXGA (1280 x 768) resolution. They will be resized to all supported screen resolutions.
- WP8 app should contain 99 x 99 pixel PNG image as app list image and at least two main tile images: small and middle one. Wide tile is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get your question what actually you want? but if you want to upload your .xap in app store than you have require

- 300x300 app icon
- 1000x800 back ground image
- If your application support multiresolution than six WXGV(768x1280) screen shots else   you need six single resolution screen shots

If you are talking about application icon than visit bellow link you got every thing

[Tile size and resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Tilesizesandresolutions)

[Tile design Guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[Multi resolution for windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

good. to know the requirements of your app or the window phone 8,  i can assume you have been using Visual Studio 2010. i have had a similar experiance to one of my apps. i simply opened my project.snl file with visual studio 2012 and at the AppManifest page, i was able to add the stuffs (images for toast, tile and other images required which i provided in various sizes). you'll also have the advantage of adding some more cool features like a better arrangement of your app which you switch the orientation. 
your app will still perform good on window phone 7 series too. 
i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To supppoert all tile sizes you will need to include the tile images for that size. If you don't, your app will still work, but the tile for your app couldn't be resized.